# What is the name of the default font in math mode?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I draw figures in Inkscape. When I label elements within the figures with variable names that I have used in the underlying TeX document, I would like them to look exactly the same as in the document. (e.g. l does not look the same as $l$)

What is the name of the math mode font so I can select it correctly in the Inkscape font list?

If the exact font should not be available, what is a similar looking font that is present on most systems?

Comment: use the Latin Modern Symbol font.

Comment: Why don't you export you document from inkscape with the latex-option. This is part of the pdf export. It will save the picture as pdf and all text as a tex file. In your document you can simply \input the generated tex file and all text is rendered with whatever font you are currently using.

Comment: @Martin H: That sounds like a good alternative, I had not heard about. Are you referring to 'Save as...-->LaTeX with PSTricks macros'? I could not find anything on a specialized pdf export. Do you have a link?

Comment: Hi, no I am referring to a feature that is available in version 0.48 of inkscape. File->save a copy, select PDF and click "save". In the next window that pops up tick the box "PDF+LaTeX". As I said before, this will generate a PDF graphic and a tex file with positioning information for all text elements. open the tex file, the comments at the top contain information about how to include it in latex documents

Comment: I wish there was a software with GUI to draw and edit figures in 2D and 3D in vectors, that allowed input of equations and be able to trace bitmaps, that have the LaTeX fonts embedded and... Well just dreaming here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The font is a math font that is not available as OpenType. No, wait: it *is*! There's the new "Latin Modern Math" that's in the new TeX Live 2011 (to be released in a few days). The font is [here](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmmath-regular.otf?view=log&pathrev=23165). I haven't seen it yet in CTAN, though. The default font is Computer Modern, but the differences with Latin Modern are negligible for your needs.

Comment: Great, the words Computer Modern lead me [here](http://typethinker.blogspot.com/2008/06/integrating-inkscape-graphics-in-latex.html). Seems that Inkscape needs a little extra love in the form of .otf fonts. I used 'LMRoman10' for the variables and am happy with the result.

Comment: @Heuke: You need to use `[text](http://url/)` in comments to add links. I took the liberty fixing it for you. See the 'help' to the right of the comment edit box for more info.

Answer (score 5):

Here a way to find this out, even when you change your font later:

For a PDF LaTeX document with only `$i$` as content (and empty pagestyle to avoid the page number) I got using `pdffonts` the font name `ZTAVXI+CMMI10` (the `CMMI10` is the important part AFAIK and stands I presume for "Computer Modern Math Italic 10pt"). My full TeXLive2010 installation included only the TeX fonts, but apparently LyX delivers it as TTF font, at least I found it under `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-lyx/cmmi10.ttf` with my Linux installation. You might need it however as OpenType font. AFAIK it might be better to not use the original default font but a newer replacement like `lmodern` (load that as package) or the font egreg mentioned in his answer.

Comment: I use `Times New Roman Italic` in Inkscape, and it's close enough for my needs. But I also wish to use `\mathbb` in Inkscape (for a complement of a knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$). What font do I have to import in Inkscape to do that? When I look at $\mathbb{R}$ in PDF, it says the font is MSBM10. Some other font, similar enough, would also suffice. Oh, and what does AFAIK mean?

Comment: Nevermind, found it with google: MSBM10.ttf download

Answer (score 2):

Full Computer Modern Math collection is available [here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html) as .otf files for use in any non-LaTeX programs suporting OpenType fonts. Same web page have also Computer Modern available.

Comment: itis already part of any TeX distribution

Comment: This are the otf files for use in non LaTeX programs - like for example Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape.

Comment: As I already wrote: They are _all_ part of your TeX distribution. Means they are already saved on your computer. Move them to the systems font directory and other programs can use the otf fonts. No need for a new download.

Comment: This link may be useful for someone looking for the font, who do not have TeX installed. He may just want figures compatibile with colegues work. Installing whole TeX distribution in order to get the fonts is not exactly elegant solution ;).