# How to get a photoshop font look like math mode in tex?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I want to make a figure in Mathematica, export it as a PDF, edit/label it in Photoshop, and then add it as a figure in a TeX document. I would really like to have the font in the figure closely match the math mode stuff in the document.

In the past I've made a PDF with TeX with just the labels I want and then pasted them all into the figures, but this is incredibly tedious.

I found this post - [What is the name of the default font in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22454/what-is-the-name-of-the-default-font-in-math-mode) - which says that the font in math mode is "Latin Modern Symbol" but this is not an option in Photoshop.

Is there another font that looks close enough to math mode which is in photoshop?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why label it in Photoshop? Why not simply write on top of the image directly in LaTeX. For example using `tikz`. Then you *are* using the same font as your article.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the comment! Because then I have to specify with xy-coords where in the figure I want to put the labels, which with a figure with several different curves (all of which I want to label), is very time consuming. With photoshop I can click and drag easily.

Comment: Latin Modern Math can be downloaded from http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html

Comment: @quantum_loser you are aware that `tikz` can give you a coordinate grid on top of the image? In the end it might be faster than instructing Photoshop to use a specific font and hope that there is no need for math in the labels.

Comment: @quantum_loser If you ponder to learn tikz or pstricks, please bear in mind that it takes weeks to learn it to a better than basic level.

Comment: If you have a standard TeX installation, you probably have the fonts in opentype format already if you're using Latin Modern. You just need to tell your operating system's font management about them. (Assuming photoshop uses the system's font management.)

Comment: @cfr I downloaded the font package but my comp tells me I need admin rights to add the font, despite the fact I AM the admin... I don't suppose either of you know know if there's a way to have photoshop look in a different folder for fonts (maybe this is a question for a different stack exchange sub)? Everything I can find with google says to just use the system font management.

Comment: No idea. With some applications, you can leave the labels and typeset them as part of your TeX code later. Or you can export the entire diagram to TeX code. But I don't suppose photoshop has those kinds of facilities ;).

Comment: You could also do it the other way around: use a font in LaTeX that is known by photoshop. This probably means you have to switch to XeLaTeX, but that's not a big deal.

Comment: The part that's on topic for us here is a dupe, while getting the font into Photoshop is out of our scope.