# What is the character used in letters in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

There are a lot of questions about the fonts used by default in latex.
However I didn't manage to find exactly the font I'm looking for. Specifically, I'm looking for the font used by latex when producing something like this:

[image]

that is, the characters used in math mode.

In particular, I'm looking not much for the numbers as for the that kind of `n`. 
Using italic Latin Modern Math, which, [if I understood correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22455/30481), is the default math font, I obtain the following:

[image]

which is clearly different from what latex reproduces (that is, the first image above).

What is the font that latex is using to produce characters like the `n` above?
And where can I find it?

Comment: what YOU get (2nd picture) is not the default.  the first may be. please give a minimal example of your code.

Comment: I'm not getting these from latex. My question is where to find the fonts *used by latex*, so that I can reproduce them on other programs. I know that the first is what latex reproduces by default, and that is what I'm trying to replicate on external programs, by finding the right font.

Comment: The second picture shows Latin Modern `slanted`, not `italic`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you run the test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
$n=2$
\end{document}
```

and look in the log file, you'll find

```
....\mathon
....\OML/lmm/m/it/10 n
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\OT1/lmr/m/n/10 =
....\penalty 500
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\OT1/lmr/m/n/10 2
....\mathoff
```

You see that actually two different fonts are used: `\OML/lmm/m/it/10` and `\OT1/lmr/m/n/10`. Now the problem is: what *physical* font is being used?

There are at least two ways for discovering it: one is to do, from the command line,

```
cat $(kpsewhich omllmm.fd)
```

that displays

```
% This file belongs to the Latin Modern package. The work is released
% under the GUST Font License. See the MANIFEST-Latin-Modern.txt and
% README-Latin-Modern.txt files for the details. For the most recent version of
% this license see http://www.gust.org.pl/fonts/licenses/GUST-FONT-LICENSE.txt
% or http://tug.org/fonts/licenses/GUST-FONT-LICENSE.txt

\ProvidesFile{omllmm.fd}[2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern]

\DeclareFontFamily{OML}{lmm}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{lmm}{m}{it}%
     {<-5.5>    lmmi5     <5.5-6.5> lmmi6
      <6.5-7.5> lmmi7     <7.5-8.5> lmmi8
      <8.5-9.5> lmmi9     <9.5-11>  lmmi10
      <11->   lmmi12
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{lmm}{b}{it}{%
       <-6> lmmib5     
      <6-8> lmmib7     
      <8->  lmmib10
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{lmm}{bx}{it}%
     {<->ssub*lmm/b/it}{}
\endinput
```

Looking for `{OML}{m}{it}` and the specification for 10pt, we find `lmmi10`. For the other font, we do

```
cat $(kpsewhich ot1lmr.fd)
```

and we see (showing just the relevant part)

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{lmr}{m}{n}%
     {<-5.5>    rm-lmr5     <5.5-6.5> rm-lmr6
      <6.5-7.5> rm-lmr7     <7.5-8.5> rm-lmr8
      <8.5-9.5> rm-lmr9     <9.5-11>  rm-lmr10
      <11-15>   rm-lmr12
      <15-> rm-lmr17
      }{}
```

so the font is `rm-lmr10`.

Second way: modify the test file to be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
$n=2$

\texttt{\fontname\csname OML/lmm/m/it/10\endcsname}

\texttt{\fontname\csname OT1/lmr/m/n/10\endcsname}
\end{document}
```

and the output will be

[image]

However, you may want to use the OpenType fonts. Then modify the test file again to be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
$n=2$
\end{document}
```

The log file, after running LuaLaTeX on the file, will show

```
....\EU2/latinmodern-math.otf(0)/m/n/10 
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\EU2/latinmodern-math.otf(0)/m/n/10 =
....\penalty 500
....\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
....\EU2/latinmodern-math.otf(0)/m/n/10 2
....\mathoff
```

So modify it again essentially as before:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
$n=2$

\texttt{\fontname\csname EU2/latinmodern-math.otf(0)/m/n/10\endcsname}

\end{document}
```

and the output will be

[image]

Now you know what font you should load in the external program.

Indeed, if I copy from the log file the  glyph and paste in a word processing application I get

[image]

Comment: @glS I think you're better using the OpenType version.

Comment: thank you very much, I was really hoping for an answer of this kind! However, while I managed to install the lmmi10 font through a .pfm that shipped with MiKTeX, I'm not sure I understand your conclusion. Copy-pasting the gliph works, but the font you name, latinmodern-math, does not produce that font

Comment: but how do I use the OpenType version? Apart from copy-pasting, using the font named latinmodern-math does not produce those gliphs

Comment: @glS You have to install the font with the system fonts. How to do it depends on your operating system.

Comment: I do know how to install a font. In fact, I have installed the latin modern math font, but this produces the glyphs I showed in the original post in the second image, not the ones produced by latex in math mode

Comment: @glS The final picture shows exactly what I got after typing ` = 2` (with Latin Modern Math as the font, as witnessed by the drop down menu at the upper left).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the default font used by latex in math mode is not latin modern, which is what I erroneously understood from, for example, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22455/30481), but Computer Modern Serif, in Italic form ***(EDIT: this is not exactly true, see comments below)***.

This font can be downloaded on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/), and produces the following output:

[image]

as well as all the other correct letters.
The number can be instead reproduced with plain Latin Modern Math (downloadable for example [here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math)):

[image]

For the equal sign there is yet some other font, to me unknown, being used.

Comment: this isn't the default either.  this is the *text italic* font.  the "original" font for math letter variables is `cmmi`, or "math italic".  but beware, "math italic" is different from `\mathit` which is really text italic letters used in a math environment to produce *words*.  numerals in math are the same as in roman text (as is all upright punctuation).  the equal sign just happens to be in the main latin text font; tex was created when space was at a real premium, so the original tex fonts bear little resemblance to current ones.